# How to solve for $x$ in $2^x+4^x=8^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, logarithms

So I was bored, and decided to do some math for fun. This was mostly to see if I could still do fairly complex math. After a while, I came up with this to see if I could still do some reasonably simple Algebra involving logarithms:$$\text{Solve for }x\text{: }2^x+4^x=8^x$$which I thought that I might be able to do. Here is my attempt at solving for $x$ in $2^x+4^x=8^x$:

---

---

$$2^x+4^x=8^x$$$$\implies1+2^x=4^x$$$$\because2^x+4^x=8^x\equiv\require{cancel}\cancel{2^x}(1+2^x)=\cancel{2^x}(4^x)\gets1+2^x=4^x$$$$2^x+1-(4^x)=\cancel{4^x-4^x}$$$$-(4^x)+2^x+1=0$$$$2^{2x}-2^x-1=0$$$$(2^x)^2-2^x-1=0$$$$a^2-a-1=0\quad\text{substituting }a\text{ for }2^x$$$$a=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4}}{2}$$$$a=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$$$$2^x=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$$$$2^x=(1\pm\sqrt5)2^{-1}$$$$x\ln(2)=\ln(1\pm\sqrt5)-\ln(2)$$$$\therefore x=\dfrac{\ln(1\pm\sqrt5)}{\ln(2)}-1$$$$\text{Or }x\approx0.6942419136306,-0.6942419136306+4.3523601i$$

---

---

##### My question

---

---

Is the solution I have achieved correct, or what could I do to attain the correct solution more easily?

---

---

###### Mistakes I might have made

---

---

1. Simplifying the logarithms (which honestly is a mistake I always seem to make)
2. The conversion to the quadratic formula (is that even a legal move I made there? I'm not sure. :\)
3. Incorrect [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) on my question
4. Incorrectly using math notation

Comment: To rephrase, letting $y=2^x$ we have $y+y^2=y^3$.  As $y\neq 0$ we can divide by it to get $1+y=y^2$ which is easily solved.  You can check the numerical part in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+2%5Ex%2B4%5Ex%3D8%5Ex)

Comment: @lulu So you're saying that my solution is correct, it's just that that is how it could be achieved faster?

Comment: why to solve this? from Youtube?

Comment: Basically, yes.  I'm just making it a bit more efficient.  And I didn't check your numbers, but WA appears to agree with you.

Comment: @MathFail Sorry about the small amount of info at the beginning, no, this is not from YT, this is something that I came up with on my own, sorry for the confusion, I should probably edit it to have more clarity.

Comment: ok, no problem.

Comment: The solution you provided seems to be correct. I was thinking if one could solve this by going for an A.M, G.M. inequality on $2^x$ and $4^x$. See if you can get your answer by using A.M, G.M.

Comment: If you're allowing complex solutions, then you'll actually get infinitely many solutions, which are the solutions you gave plus integer multiples of $2\pi i / \ln(2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the following by $2^x$ since it is valid for any $x$,
$$
2^x + 4^x = 8^x \rightarrow  \frac{2^x}{2^x} + \frac{4^x}{2^x} = \frac{8^x}{2^x} \implies 1 + 2^x =(2^x)^2
$$
Let $y=2^x$, we get
$$
1+y=y^2 \implies y_{1,2} = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
Now we compute $x$; hence,
$$
2^x = \frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2} \rightarrow \ln2^x = \ln\left(\frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \implies x = \dfrac{\ln\left(\frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}{\ln 2}
$$

Because $\sqrt{5} > 1$ and the logarithm is not defined for a negative input, we discard $\frac{1- \sqrt{5}}{2}$; therefore, the equation has one real solution.

Answer (score 1):

$2^x+4^x=8^x$. $u=2^x$. $u+u^2=u^3. \implies u^3-u^2-u=0$

$u(u^2-u-1)=0\implies u\in \{0,\frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}\}$

So not exactly a real solution, but $x\to -\infty$ works. $x=\ln (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})/\ln 2 $ is a solution.

$\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}(e^{\pi i})$

$x=\ln(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})/\ln (2)=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})/\ln(2)+\pi i/\ln(2)$. is another complex solution.